# "Missing Return Statement" - will not compile

Tags: java, methods, compiler-warnings

The following method should return the powers of 2 from 0 to n. However, I'm getting an error that says my code did not compile because of missing return statement. 
Note: this is from an online site associated with my textbook (Building Java Programs, 3E, Reges & Stepp). We are only supposed to just write the method(s) described in the problem statement.

```
public static int printPowersof2(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        int number = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
        return number; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the reason of the loop? You are returning from your method at first chance.

Comment: place a `return` statement outside the loop since the loop may not execute for negative numbers

Comment: Do you understand what `return` means?  You say the method should "return" several powers of 2, but the method name indicates that it's supposed to "print" them.  Plus you've declared the result type to be `int`, which means it can only _return_ one integer.  I suspect you need to review the basics of method calls.

Comment: Please look over [this tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site?  I'd be interested in seeing just what it says about the method you're supposed to write, since I'm not sure you're on the right track at all.

Comment: Link: http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/index.jsp but you need an account. This is my first day ever working with Java, so yah I'm likely all jacked-up. I hesitated to even post this question.

Comment: Here is the text of the question: "Write a method called printPowersOf2 that accepts a maximum number as an argument and prints each power of 2 from 20 (1) up to that maximum power, inclusive. For example, consider the following calls:

printPowersOf2(3);
printPowersOf2(10);
These calls should produce the following output:

1 2 4 8
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024
You may assume that the value passed to printPowersOf2 is 0 or greater."

Comment: OK, thanks.  I suspected it was something like this.

Comment: Actually, the `practiceit.cs.washington.edu` site says there's a list of problems I can view without an account.  But if I click on the link for this, a page comes up saying there was an internal server error, because something raised `NullPointerException`.  So maybe the guys at `practiceit.cs.washington.edu` need to practice Java a little more themselves??!!?  (Or it could be a bug in Apache software...)

Answer (score 3):

You must have a return statement outside the loop, since the loop may not be executed at all if n is negative, in which case the method won't have a return value.

```
public static int printPowersof2(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        int number = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
        return number; 
    }
    return 0; // it's up to you to decide what to return in this case
}
```

That said, as mentioned in the comments, there's a problem with the method's logic.
If, as the name suggests, the method should print all powers of 2 up to n, it should not return when i is 0. The return statement should appear only outside the loop.

```
public static int printPowersof2(int n) {
    int number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        number = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
        System.out.println(number);            
    }
    return number;
}
```

I wasn't sure what the return value should be. If you want to return all the powers of 2 instead of just printing them, your method should return a List or an array.

```
public static int[] printPowersof2(int n) {
    if (n<0)
        return new int[0];
    int[] result = new int[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        result[i] = (int) Math.pow(2, i);           
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That explains the error message--but this code has much more serious problems than that.

Comment: @ajb Yeah, you're right. I focused on the compilation error without really examining the logic.

Comment: @Eran No worries, I almost did the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return multiple results (in your case, the powers of 2 from 0 to n), you need to return a collection of some sort, e.g. a list:

```
public static List<Integer> printPowersof2(int n) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        list.add((int) Math.pow(2, i));
    }
    return list;
}
```

or an array:

```
public static int[] printPowersof2(int n) {
    int[] result = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        result[i] = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually want to `return` anything.  The question says "Write a method called printPowersOf2 that accepts a maximum number as an argument and prints each power of 2 from 20 (1) up to that maximum power, inclusive."  This says nothing about *returning* any values.

`return`, and result types, are something you use if you want to be able to call a method in an expression, and use its value.  For example:

```
double d = Math.sqrt(5);
```

will set `d` to the square root of 5.  For this to work, the `sqrt` method must be declared to return a value (actually a `double`), and there has to be a `return` statement somewhere in the method body of `sqrt`, which tells it what the value will be.  In the above statement, that value, the one that gets `return`'ed, will be assigned into `d`.

In your case, though, you don't want to set anything to a value.  You will never want to do something like

```
int something = printPowersOf2(10);
```

because the purpose of `printPowersOf2` is to print results, not to compute a value that can be used in an expression.

Therefore, the result type of the method should be `void`:

```
public static void printPowersOf2(int n) {
    ...
}
```

and the body must not contain any `return` statements that contain a value.  (`return;` statements with no value are OK.)  The body will print values (using `System.out.println`, probably), but it will not return any values.

Comment: Thanks. I'll review return. Last time I wrote this much code it was on 80-column punch cards. No joke.

Comment: Fortran, or COBOL?  (For me, it was COBOL, around 1976-77.  I was thrilled when we finally purchased an editing program that we could use with a terminal, so we didn't have to make our program patches with punch cards.)

Comment: FORTRAN back in '79 or '80, in high school. We'd write our programs in class and go to the local uni's computer lab to type up the punch cards and run them on their system. Fast 1 day turnaround time for each run!

Answer (score 0):

Put return outside the loop.

```
public static int printPowersof2(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        int number = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
        sum = sum + number;
        System.out.println(number + " : " + sum); // will print current calculated result & sum of it
    }
   return sum; // I have returned sum, you can return whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for the help. As noted above, I was confused by void and return. Here is the working method:

```
public static void printPowersOf2(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        int number = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
        System.out.print(number);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```